# in my django template my input is reset when I send the search

Tags: django, django-templates

What do I need to put in the value parameters of my inputs so that this information is forwarded to the fields?

You can see what I'm talking about by entering the page and verify that when a search is made all my entries are restarted

here is my html code in case it was necessary

```
<input
    id="kword"
    name="kword"
    value=""

    class="input-form search-box"
    type="search"
    placeholder="Profesión, palabra clave o empresa"
    data-ac="//ac.careerjet.net/ns"
    data-target="#ac-s"
    data-target2="#s"
    data-as="1"
    data-lc="es_MX"

    data-mhd="10"

    data-mhm="3"
  >

<input
    id="location"
    name="location"
    value=""

    class="input-form search-box"
    type="search"
    placeholder="Ubicacion"
    data-ac="//ac.careerjet.net/ns"
    data-target="#ac-s"
    data-target2="#s"
    data-as="1"
    data-lc="es_MX"

    data-mhd="10"

    data-mhm="3"
  >

<select name="type" id="type">
                                    <option value="Todos">Todos</option>
                                    <option value="Remoto">Remoto</option>
                                    <option value="Presencial">Presencial</option>
                                </select>

<select name="sort" id="sort">
                                    <option value="relevance">Relevancia</option>
                                    <option value="date">Fecha</option>
                                    <option value="salary">Salario</option>
                                </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the text input I only have to put in the value="{{ request.GET.kword }}"